# Python multiprocessing same function with different arguments

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a program that is designed to calculate order parameter from coarse-grained molecular system. In the system the I have different beads, which represents different parts of molecule. Each of these beads have a xyz-coordinates that represent their place in the system. The program works, but it is very slow since I have to calculate the number of beads type i around beads type j within a certain cutoff distance.

**Function to calculate Euclidean distance between bead a and b:**

```
def distance_ab(a, b):
n_beads = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        # Euclidean distance
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((a[i] - b[j])** 2, axis=0))
        if dist <= 1.0 and dist > 0.0: # cut-off distance
            n_beads += 1

return n_beads
```

So I decided to fasten the process of calculating the distance between different beads by using python multiprocessing library. But for some reason I can not get the multiprocessing to work for repeating the same distance calculation function with different parameters (xyz-data of beads). Multiprocessing returns a list of some numbers, when the idea is to return only one number (the number of beads in certain cut-off distance). What I do wrong and could someone help me to understand where the problem is?

**The part where I am trying to use multiprocessing:**

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()) as pool:

    # go through certain number of molecular simulation frames (e.g. 100 frames)
    for i in range(frames)):  
        
        # Calculating euclidean distances between different types of beads 
        # for each frame 
        a_b = pool.starmap(calculate_distances, zip(bead_a_array, bead_b_array))
        a_c = pool.starmap(calculate_distances, zip(bead_a_array, bead_c_array))
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: While this question is probably a better fit here (since it is mainly about how to use a general python library), if you have more specific questions about molecular simulation, they may be better suited on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

When you `zip` together your bead arrays, you are creating an iterable of tuples that overall has the same length as the shorter of the two arrays.

```py
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[4,5,6,7]
>>> res=zip(A,B)
>>> list(res)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) for `starmap`:

> Like map() except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an iterable of [(1,2), (3, 4)] results in [func(1,2), func(3,4)].

So your `starmaps` are actually just passing a pair of elements (one from each array) to your function and returning the result for each of these pairs. If you want to use multiprocessing to determine, say, the number of b and c beads within the cutoff distance of a at the same time, you would need to do something like this:

```py
import itertools as it

all_arr=[bead_a_array,bead_b_array,bead_c_array]
with multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    a_counts=pool.starmap(distance_ab, it.combinations(all_arr,2))
```

Here, instead of passing individual elements of each array to the function, it now passes each array into your function and it will compute the counts of b and c within the threshold of a (and c with the threshold of b) simultaneously. The `it.combinations(all_arr,2)` selects unique pairs of arrays to pass to your function.